# I want to know how i can from the path of the file selected use the same path to download the XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a Html form that has a button capable of generating a XML file and downloading it to the users computers.

This is my XML.js file that writes all xml information and then donwloads the file to the user computer.

```
function downloadData(contentType,data,filename){
  "use strict";
  var link=document.createElement("A");
  link.setAttribute("href",encodeURI("data:"+contentType+","+data));
  link.setAttribute("style","display:none");
  link.setAttribute("download",filename);
  document.body.appendChild(link); //needed for firefox
  console.log(link.outerHTML);
  link.click();
  setTimeout(function(){
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  },1000);
}
```

Function that gets the answers from the form

```
function fromToXml(form){
 "use strict";
 var xmldata=['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'];
 var inputs=form.elements;
 xmldata.push("<AssetInfo>");

 // file name*****************************

 for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){ 

    if(inputs[i].value){ 

        xmldata.push("  <customMetaData>");

        xmldata.push("     <key>"+inputs[i].placeholder+"</key>");

        xmldata.push("     <value>"+inputs[i].value+"</value>");

      xmldata.push("  </customMetaData>");
   }
 }
 xmldata.push("</AssetInfo>");
 return xmldata.join("\n");

 }


function download(frm){
"use strict";
 var data=fromToXml(frm);
 console.log(data);

 // file name

downloadData("text/xml",data,"hello.xml");
}
```

HTML Button that calls the funtion inside XML.js

```
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="download(this.form)" 
id="input">GerarXML</button>
```

HTML Button that asks the user to select a file

```
 <input type="file" id="fileinput" nwdirectory  multiple />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a back-end service in php that reads the file name and then store it in variable, and when generate the xml call the same variable.